# What is "string universality"?

Tags: string-theory, supergravity

I encountered the notion of "string universality" in the [TASI lectures on Supergravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2051) (April 2011). What does this actually mean? Does it mean that every consistent (in particular cancellation of anomalies) supergravity theory has as UV-completion a string theory? After a bit of googling on it, it rather seems to be considered as a bit problematic because every kind of consistent supergravity would have UV-string completion according to the concept, even a 4D-supergravity theory.

As I am a novice in string theory (I have some basic knowledge of supergravity though) So I would appreciate an explanation without too much jargon. Thank you.

Comment: What's "problematic" about the (conjectured) universality for 4 dimensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String universality is the conjecture that every consistent supergravity QFT arises as the low-energy effective QFT of a suitable [compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(physics)) (essentially a choice of "small" compact dimensions that are to small to detect as dimensions in the effective theory) of (10-dimensional) string theory. The origin of this idea is in [*"String Universality in Six Dimensions"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0987) by Kumar and Taylor, where they show this for a large class of 6d SUGRAs.

The dimensionality of the effective QFT is "adjustable" by choosing a suitable compactification - e.g. for 6d SUGRAs the compactification manifold is four-dimensional, and for 4d SUGRAs the compactification manifold is six-dimensional.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! So due to the large number of possible compactifications (there is no unique compactification) one gets the numerous string vacua (Or am I completely wrong)?

Answer (score 5):

The five consistent superstring theories are UV-complete and consistent quantum theories of gravity; that's demonstrably true. Adding M-theory (the eleven-dimensional supergravity) to that set of maximally uncompactified theories, you can obtain a huge *landscape* of effective field theories obtained as compactifications of those string/M-theories.

***Question:*** Is the set of all EFTs obtained from string theory a complete list of all the possible EFTs that can be consistently coupled to gravity?

The phrase *"string universality"* is the statement that the answer to the aforementioned question is affirmative.

String universality examples:

1. 32 supercharges in d=11 and d=10. The only consistent (anomaly-free) supergravities are the eleven-dimensional supergravity, one non-chiral theory (the IIA one) and another chiral (2,0) one. All of them arise as low energy limits of string/M-theories.
2. 16 supercharges in d=10. Anomaly cancellation does only allow four possibilities: $E_{8} \times E_{8}$, $SO(32)$ , $E_{8} \times U(1)^{248}$ and $U(1)^{496}$. Heterotic strings realize the first two ones and amazingly, an anomaly-inflow argument can be [invoked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilteJ-fBd4k&t=3252s) to show that the other two options are inconsistent. Again, string theory exactly covers the space of all posibilities.
3. See [String Universality in Six Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.0987) and the talk [The Swampland in d larger than 6](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4mVehN-FbQ) for amazing dicussions for (2,0) theories in 6d.

I recommend the talk [Supersymmetric Quantum Field Theories and the Swampland](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ilteJ-fBd4k&t=3252s) for more examples that exhibit the amazing match between string theory and all the consistent theories that can be coupled to gravity (specially in six dimensions).

**Nowadays the common jargon for "string universality" is the ["string lampost principle"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.11729): The space of all possible EFTs that can be consistently coupled to quantum gravity are realizable as EFTs derived from string theory.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually I don't understand the $\bf{Question}$. it seems, a verb is missing. And I have the same impression with the following sentence ... I don't understand it neither well.